# Print result from two functions to console

Tags: applescript

I've created a small script to get the current size and position of a window. Unfortunately, I only can get one result at a time and need to comment/uncomment the other one.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Toggl Track"
    # get position of window 1
    get size of window 1
end tell
```

If I uncomment both, I will only get the size.

So, my I tried to write the results in a variable and then log these instead.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Toggl Track"
    set position to get position of window 1
    set size to get size of window 1
    log position & size
end tell
```

With this, I get no result at all.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position` and `size` are part of the terminology of `System Events`. You cannot use them as variable names. Rename the variables

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Toggl Track"
    set windowPosition to position of window 1
    set windowSize to size of window 1
    log windowPosition & windowSize
end tell
```

Regarding the first script, `get` saves the result of the line in the `AppleScript` property `result` and overwrites previous values.